# Problems with AWS Amplify, Next.js and authenticated SSR

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, next.js, aws-amplify

I've got a Next.js application that uses AWS Cognito userpools for authentication.  I have a custom UI and am using the `aws-amplify` package directly invoking `signIn`/`signOut`/etc... in my code. (I previously used the AWS Hosted UI and had the same problem set out below - I hoped switching and digging into the actual APIs who reveal my problem but it hasn't)

Everything in development (running on localhost) is working correctly - I'm able to login and get access to my current session both in a page's render function using

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
...
export default const MyPage = (props) => {
    useEffect(async () => {
        const session = await Auth.currentSession();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and during SSR

```
import { withSSRContext } from 'aws-amplify';
...
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    ...
    const SSR = withSSRContext(context);
    const session = await SSR.Auth.currentSession();
    ...
}
```

However, when I deploy to AWS Amplify where I run my staging environment, the call to get the current session during SSR fails.  This results in the page rendering as if the user is not logged in then switching when the client is able to determine that the user is in fact logged in.

Current Hypothesis - missing cookies(??):

I've checked that during the login process that the AWS cookies are being set correctly in the browser.  I've also checked and devtools tells me the cookies are correctly being sent to the server with the request.

However, if I log out `context.req.headers` inside `getServerSideProps` in my staging environment, the cookie header is missing (whereas in my dev environment it appears correctly).  If this is true, this would explain what I'm seeing as `getServerSideProps` isn't seeing my auth tokens, etc... but I can't see why the cookie headers would be stripped?

Has anyone seen anything like this before?  Is this even possible?  If so, why would this happen?  I assume I'm missing something, e.g. config related, but I feel like I've followed the docs pretty closely - my current conf looks like this

```
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {...}
    ssr: true
});
```

Next.js version is `11.1.2` (latest)

Any help very much appreciated!

Comment: Hey were you able to solve the above issue? If yes could you clarify how and reasons behind it?

Comment: Not yet I'm afraid.  For now, I have worked around as I do not need the authenticated version of pages to be indexed by search engines, so can just serve the unauthenticated versions via SSR.  I then have client code that delays display of the page until authentication status has been checked to ensure we show the right version rather show unauthenticated version then quickly flick to authenticated version.

Not ideal, but works for now pending more time to investigate

Comment: hm.. Thanks for the info.

Comment: are you using cloudfront?

Comment: No, it’s just an Amplify app based off a git repo stored in CodeCommit. The build settings are all auto detected but with a custom domain added.  So probably as close to a vanilla setup as possible.

Comment: OK. Probably different but on my end the CloudFront distribution was not passing all the HTTP headers to the ELB (we are using fargate). A quick way to check this was to try to access the ELB <replace>.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com) directly. Hope this helps someone and you find the answer to your issue.

Comment: Please provide `package.json` scripts and `amplify.yml` settings here for debugging

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Next@11.0.0 to use getServerSideProps, withSSRContext and Auth module in production.

Comment: Op mentioned that "Next.js version is 11.1.2 (latest)"

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.
My solution was that disconnect a branch has an authentication problem once and reconnect the branch.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Finally, I found the cause.
Are you using Amplify's access control feature to apply Basic authentication?
I don't know the exact reason, but I have confirmed that there is no problem right after deployment, but after a few hours, the same problem occurs.
The solution is to use CloudFront Functions to insert your own authentication mechanism into the Viewer Request.

Answer (score 0):

What are your build settings? I guess you are using `next build && next export` in which case this `getServerSideProps` shall not work. See https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features

To use SSR with AWS amplify see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/server-side-rendering-amplify.html#redeploy-ssg-to-ssr or consider deploying on a node server that is actually a server that you can start with `next start` like [AWS EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/deploy-nodejs-web-app/) or deploy on [Vercel](https://vercel.com/solutions/nextjs).

Otherwise if you use `next export` have to make do with client side data fetch only with client side updates only and cannot use dynamic server side features of nextjs.

Comment: AWS Amplify supports SSR - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/server-side-rendering-amplify.html#supported-unsupported-features

- `getServerSideProps` runs fine, can perform server-side API calls and generate pages fine - it's just that it does so as if the user is not authenticated, even though they are

Comment: @James Loxam yes but the package.json scripts should be `"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start"
},`. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/server-side-rendering-amplify.html#redeploy-ssg-to-ssr

Comment: @James Loxam as a debugging step, add a console.log line to `getServerSide` props. If you see the line printed in build step, you need to correct your `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

One reason for `context.req.headers` not having any `cookie` in it is because CloudFront distribution is not forwarding any cookies.

This “[CloudFront Behaviour](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#RequestCustomCookies)” can be changed in two ways:

1. Forward all cookies, OR
2. Forward specified cookies (i.e. array of cookie names)

To change the behaviour, navigate to CloudFront on AWS console > Distributions > your_distribution > Behaviors Tab.

Then Edit existing or Create new behaviour > Change cookies settings (for example set it to "All")

[image: cloudfront-cookie-behaviour]